# How to show the date continously even without a value using php or mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I create a table to show the data from my database. I want to add a row even there is no value from database. As you can see to my sample it only show Monday to Friday because their is a data in it from the db. I want to show saturday and sunday as well. I have tried MySQL ADDDATE() and PHP date_add(). But it only move my date according to the interval i add.

Here is my code in sql:

```
select str_to_date(date,"%Y-%m-%d") as time_stamp, min(time), max(time), 
from attendance;
```

Code in php:

```
<td><?php echo  $list->time_stamp ?>, <?php echo date('D', strtotime($list->time_stamp)) ;?></td>
<td><?php echo  substr($list->m_time, 0,5)?></td>
<td><?php echo  substr($list->mx_time, 0,5)?></td>
```

and here is my output:

[image]

or could i use php to show monday to sunday? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your example, I think you can do this:

```
select d.date, min(t.time), max(t.time)
from (select date from attendance t union 
      select date + interval 1 day from attendance  union
      select date + interval 2 day from attendance
     ) d left join
     attendance t
     on date(t.date) = d.date
group by d.date;
```

The subquery essentially generates a bunch of dates from your data.  By looking two days ahead, you are sure to get the weekend days.

Comment: It is not working. I'm selecting multiple columns and have multiple joins. Is their another solution other than adding interval?

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to solve this in SQL, it just gets messy, and you don't want that. Assuming we're not talking about a huge amount of data I would do this in two steps:

1. Read the data from your database into an PHP array.
2. Display a line for each day from the lowest date to the highest date in the array.

Since you gave no PHP code to work with I have to make up my own example, so it will be simple. First of all you need to order your array, this is best done in MySQL:

```
select 
  time_to_sec(date) as time_stamp, 
  min(time) as min_time, 
  max(time) as max_time, 
from attendance
order by date ASC
```

Reading this data into an array should not be a problem. The first item in the array will contain the first date, the last item the last date.

```
$currentIndex = 0;
$currentDate  = $attendances[$currentIndex]['time_stamp'];
$lastDate     = $attendances[count($dates)-1]['time_stamp'];
do {
  echo date('l jS \of F Y',$currentDate).' ';
  if (abs($currentDate-$attendances[$currentIndex]['time_stamp']) < 60) {
    echo $attendances[$currentIndex]['min_time'].' '; 
    echo $attendances[$currentIndex]['max_time'].'<br>';  
    $currentIndex++;
  }
  else echo "--:-- --:--<br>";    
  $currentDate += 60*60*24;               // assuming timestamp is in seconds
} while ($currentDate < $lastDate-60);    // subtract a minute, just to be sure
```

Then you loop through all days from start to finish. $currentDate goes up by one day worth of seconds every step. $currentIndex only goes up after data has been used from the array. This way you can fill in the gaps. Note that I have used a real timestamp to make it easier to compute with dates.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What would be the output of this?

Comment: `Monday 8th of August 2005 10:32 12:34` and `Saterday 13th of August 2005 --:-- --:--`. Not a table like you had. I said it would be simple.

Comment: Im confused. So it will not show the date for whole week? Just monday and saturday?

Comment: Yes, it will show lines with continuous days of the week, including those for which there's no data in the database. That's what you wanted, wasn't it? If you try to understand the code you'll see how this works: It just goes through all the days, picking up any data along the way.

Comment: One assumption I made was that the 'date' field in your database only contains dates, and not times as well. This does happen often in databases: A field is called 'date' but it contains date and time information.

Comment: I finally figure out what to do!`$date1 = strtotime("2014-08-01");
$date2 = strtotime("2014-08-08");
do 
{
// echo $date1;
echo date("Y-m-d", $date1)."<br>";
$date1 = strtotime("+1 day", $date1);
} while ($date1 <= $date2);` all i need to do is to build a table or rows from it. But how?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a date calendar Table 
have full day you want 
then use use it left join your Table attendance

then you will get u want

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. How can i do that? Wouldn't it will be better if a just format my current table than to left join from another table?